# What happens to the ERC-20 tokens that are "migrated" (e.g. to VeChain); do the ERC-20 tokens remain at the original address?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, erc-20, migration

I'm asking for the mechanical explanation of what happens to the ERC-20 token data at the original address; post migration to a new chain.  For example, if I had 100 LivePeer (LPT) ERC-20 tokens at address "x"; had them migrated onto VeChain.  What remains at address "x"?  Do the original ERC-20 tokens disappear?  Or do they stay behind (visible in etherscan) but are basically deprecated/dead?

Answer (score 1):

When some one migarates tokens from one blockchain to other; the tokens actually don't move.

Let's say you have a `MetaTokenETH` on ethereum chain and then you create another token `MetaTokenV` on vChain.

Generally users are asked to `swap` the tokens from Eth to VChain. So you can send your `MetaTokenETH` to some adress (maybe a contract) and get equivalent `MetaTokenV` on vChain (mostly on same address, if both chains are EVM compatible). The `MetaTokenETH` you sent are burned (or locked in some contract) so no one can claim them again.

PS: I have mentioned generally and mostly quite often because it completly depends on the implementor on how they want their users to convert their tokens.